# Multiply text file in Unix by a constant

Tags: shell

How can a text file be multiplied in by a constant using shell commands?
For e.g there is a text file consisting the following numbers

```
    -255.9641842033 
    -255.9667588863 
    -256.9777650145 
    -258.9777662459 
    -259.9777661194
```

This needs to be multiplied with a constant 19.123456789123 and save in new text file. How can the above be accomplished?
Looking forward to a reply.

Comment: [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138133/multiplication-of-every-line) might help.

Comment: Thanks. My file also has 8 blank spaces before the numerical values. And how to preserve the precision to 12 decimal points while multiplication.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This might be close, using Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/([+-]?[0-9.]+)/$1*19.123456789123/ge' YourFile
```

**Sample Output**

```
-4894.92001617493 
-4894.96925301402 
-4914.3031850202 
-4952.55012214707 
-4971.67357651707
```

That kind of says... "*capture anything that starts with an optional plus or minus and has a bunch digits and decimal points and call it capture group 1. Replace that with whatever it was multiplied by your magic number. The `e` at the end, says to **evaluate** the right side as an expression rather than take it as a literal. The `g` at the end says to do it each and every time it occurs on each line, rather than just the first time."*

Comment: It would be nice if the down-voter had the courtesy to explain what is so horrendously wrong with an answer that the OP accepts as doing what he wants instead of a cowardly, drive-by shooting-down.