# Increase numbers in file using sed and regexp

Tags: string, unix, sed, find

I want to increase all numbers in file by 1000 with follow pattern:

```
'... comment_count') VALUES ( 15132, ...
'... comment_count') VALUES ( 15133, ...
'... comment_count') VALUES ( 16134, ...
.
.
```

I want after change output be like this:

```
'... comment_count') VALUES ( 16132, ...
'... comment_count') VALUES ( 16133, ...
'... comment_count') VALUES ( 17134, ...
.
.
```

I tried something like this but not work:

```
 sed -r 's/`comment_count`\) VALUES \( (\d+)/echo "\1\1$((\1+1000))\"/ge'  test.txt
```

Comment: Sed has no idea of arithmetics or even numbers – it only knows strings, so doing any math in sed is very painful.

Comment: This should show you a way with `Perl` https://stackoverflow.com/a/49359391/2836621

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[0-9]\+/$((&+1000))/g;s/.*/echo "&"/e' file
```

Replace each set of numbers by a bash numeric expression. Evaluate the entire line with an echo command.

Answer (score 2):

`sed` cannot do maths or string manipulations in replacement.

You may use this `perl` solution:

```
perl -pe "s~(comment_count'\)\h+VALUES\h+\(\h+)(\d+)~\$1.(\$2+1000)~e" file
```

```
'... comment_count') VALUES ( 16132, ...
'... comment_count') VALUES ( 16133, ...
'... comment_count') VALUES ( 17134, ...
```

Comment: hi, i have a question is beyond sed. For example, with .net, does it have a function that does not require a loop but does it? is regex.replace possible? I would love to have a function can custom multiple char at one like sed

Comment: `sed` is Turing-complete, so it can do all other languages can do. It "just" requires a different way of thinking, and it is unquestionably unreadable when performing non basic tasks. But the readability is still not that bad [in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60729013/5825294).

Comment: @anubhava unfortunately not maybe because file is very big. I regenerated file from scratch again using new IDs :/. anyway thank you

Comment: Well you never mentioned anything about big file processing in question.

Answer (score 2):

The answer assumes all lines have the format shown in the OP.

The following `sed` script, run with `sed -E -f plus1000 inputfile` (`-E` is to use `(`, `{`, and the likes, instead of `\(`, `\{`, and the others), does the job:

```
# this file is named plus1000
s/([^0-9][0-9]*)([0-9])([0-9]{3})/\1\n\2\n\3/
:a
h
s/.*\n(.)\n.*/\1/
y/0123456789/1234567890/
G
/^0/{
  s/0\n(.*)(.)\n.\n(.*)/\1\n\2\n0\3/
  ta
}
s/(.)\n(.*)\n.\n(.*)/\2\1\3/
```

Explanation:

1. the top `s/…/…/` command encloses the fourth significant digint in between two newlines `\n`;

   - the content of the pattern space would match `^.*\n[0-9]\n.*$`
   - the content of the hold space is irrelevant (we don't care what the content is)
2. the `:a` label marks the line where a *do-while* loop begins;

   - no changes to pattern and hold spaces
3. the `h` command copies the content of the pattern space (the current line as it has become), overwriting whatever was in it;

   - the pattern space is unchanged
   - the hold space is equal to the pattern space
4. this other `s/…/…/` command removes whatever surrounds the digit that was "highlighted" at step 1;

   - the pattern space only contains one digit, i.e. it has the form `^[0-9]$`
   - the hold space is unchanged
5. the `y` command transform each digit in its successor, except for 9 which becomes 0, thus implying that the following digit on the left should be increased by 1 too;

   - the pattern space only contains one digit, which is increased by 1 with respect to the previous step
   - the hold space is unchanged
6. the `G` command appends the content of the hold space to the pattern space

   - the hold space is unchanged
   - the pattern space is the digit just increased in step 5, followed by a newline `\n`, followed by the content of the hold space
7. `/^0/` limits the action of the commands grouped in `{` and `}` only to pattern space that has a leading `0` (that previously was a `9`)

   7.1. the third `s/…/…/` command deletes the newline added in step 6, and moves the other two newlines around the next (to the left) digit

   7.2. the `t` command in tests if the previous substitution actually happened and, if so, it transfer control to the line labelled at step 2 (actually to the line after it, as `:a` performs no action)
8. if we reach here, we have added 1 to a digit other than 9, so further processing is not needed, so the fourth and last `s/…/…/` command reorders the pieces and removes the newlines.

Comment: Amazing and awesome solution!