# How can I split a text based on every n.th words?

Tags: unix, awk

I am trying to split a text file for every 1000th word.

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' 'END{print NR+0}' filename
```

with awk I can count the words in a file but I don't know how I can split it.

final output= filename(1).txt, filename(2).txt

Comment: Welcome. What exactly do you mean by word? And that is more complicated than it seems. If you have a word for each line, that awk will say the number of words is only `1`!

Comment: Does each line contain only one word? If not, do you want to preserve the fact that some words are on the same line?

Comment: If it's one word per line, just use `split`, not `awk`.

Comment: No  it has more than one word per line.

Answer (score 0):

This totally sick solution should work for files which are less than 10000 words:

```
. <(echo -e 'uno due tre\nquattro\ncinque sei sette otto\nnove dieci undici dodici tredici' | sed -zE '
s/^/\x0/
:a
y/012345678/123456789/
s/\x0(([^ \n]+[ \n]+){4})/cat > file0 <<EOF\n\1\nEOF\n\x0/
ta
s/\x0(.*)/cat > file0 <<EOF\n\1\nEOF\n\x0/
s/\n+/\n/g')
```

Essentially, it intersperses some code at the points where the splits have to occur in such a way that the outcoming file is a `bash` script which is a sequence of `cat` commands which read from a *heredocument* and write to a file (a maximum of 10 files is allowed!). This script is sourced (`. file` is just `source file`, just uglier). You can see the script by removing the leading `. <(` and the trailing `)`.

The nice thing is that it splits the big file in the middle of lines if necessary, without altering the lines where no split occurs.

The ugliest thing is that it numbers the files backward.

The limitation on the number of words is because I am implementing only a one-digit addition on the filenames; it can be removed by implementing an addition in a similar way as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60729013/5825294) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60732433/5825294).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `awk` without too much trouble. It helps keep the clutter down if you write a function to actually handle outputting the words from an array to your file. Keep a counter to number the output file names, e.g. `wordsfile_1` (first 1000 words), `wordsfile_2` (next 1000 words) and so on. Then it is just a matter of keeping track of how many words you add to your array and call your output function when you hit 1000 words. Then delete the array, to make it ready to hold the next 1000 words, reset your word counter and keep going.

For example you could do something like:

```
awk '
    function writefile() {
        fname="wordsfile_" ++c + 0
        for (j=1; j<=n; j++)
            print a[j] > fname
        delete a
        n = 0
    }
    {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            a[++n] = $i
            if (n == 1000)
                writefile()
        }
    }
END {
    writefile()
}' input_file
```

The `function writefile()` handles writing the output to your 1000 word files and deleting the array and resetting the counter `n`. The END rule just calls the function once more to output any words collected since the last output.

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: It does the charm :)
Can we remain the consistency of the file? Can we print the words as they positioned instead of one word in a line?

Comment: Can we modify it so it can print line number next or before the word so we can grab the line number?         .
example:

"Lorem 220
ipsum 221
dolor 221"      

          .awk 'NR == 1000' wordsfile_1 | awk -F'[^0-9]*' '$0=$2'
then, we can use the result here: awk 'NR >= 1 && NR <= 221(result)' filename > filename_1. I think, I can put it in a for loop and it can generate files.

Comment: Sure you can add another counter for the total number of words seen and just write that output before the word written to the file. If you use `total` as the counter, then just write `printf "%4d  %s\n", total, a[j] > fname`  (using `printf` will allow you to set the field-width of the number)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
for FILE in *.txt
do
#FILE="FILENAME.txt" 
read -p "HOW MANY WORDS SHOULD BE IN YOUR FILES? (~ APPROXIMATE) " BUFFER
#BUFFER=1000 # APPROXIMATE NUMBER OF WORDS IN A FILE 

NW=$(wc -w $FILE | awk '{print $1}') #NW=NUMBER OF WORDS IN YOUR FILE

if [[ $NW -gt $BUFFER ]]
then

LINENUMBER=$(wc -l $FILE | awk '{print $1}')
WCOUNT=0
FL=1 #FIRST LINE NUMBER OF EVERY NEW FILE
FN=1 #FILE NUMBER

for j in $(eval echo "{1..$LINENUMBER}")
do
    INC=$(sed -n "${j}p" $FILE | wc -w)
    WCOUNT=$(( WCOUNT + INC ))
    if [[ $WCOUNT -gt $BUFFER ]];
    then
        sed -n "${FL},${j}p" $FILE >  ${FILE%%.*}_${FN}.txt
        FL=$(( j + 1))
        (( FN++ ))
        WCOUNT=0
    fi
done
sed -n "${FL},\$p" $FILE >  ${FILE%%.*}_${FN}.txt
fi 
done
```

I found a different solution, It generates files that have roughly 1000 words in each.